# Cómo agregar un objeto con un indice dentro de un arreglo, forEach/map?

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, test

En primer lugar tengo dos arreglo vacio

```
let people = [];
let families = []
```

luego tengo un método de un objeto

```
let methods = {
   addPerson: function(name, age, family){

 //acá tengo que crear una nueva persona con esos parametros
 //además de los datos de nombre edad y familia también asignarle un numero de index --> será el numero de familia asignado al personaje que inicie en 1 y no 0
 //lo que yo hice fue:

let newPerson = {name, age, family,};

    people.forEach((curr, index, arr)=>{
      if(arr.indexOf(newPerson) === -1 ){
        people.push([newPerson, index]);
      }
    })
    return newCharacter;

     
  }
}
```

Se me ocurrió hacer eso, y también probé un map, pero no tengo idea cómo arreglarlo, los errores que me devuelve son:

-que no estoy agregando personas al arreglo
Expected length: 1
Received length: 0
Received array:  []

-no estoy agregando bien la familia de la persona por medio del index en el array de familias
el test me dice que cuando haga
Methods.listPerson()[0].familiaId.toEqual(1)

este listPeople es otro metodo que tengo, pero no lo agregué acá ya que simplemente me devuelve un arreglo con todas las personas, el tema es agregar bien cada una segun lo que me pide

Ayuda para entender!! Puedo usar un forEach como se me ocurrió o qué sería mejor??

Comment: Pero estas tratando de recorrer un arreglo inicializado en vacío... entonces no va a entrar nunca al ciclo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varias pautas:

`#1:` Por qué agregas la persona y el indice juntos?, es decir, porque haces esto?

```
push([newPerson, index])
```

No tiene sentido por donde lo veas, ya que para poder acceder a esa persona requeriras previamente tener un indice, y el indice seria el mismo que el que tienes en tu segunda pocision del arreglo, por lo que seria hacer algo redundante.

`#2:` comparar un objeto con otro siempre te dara `false` a menos de que los dos objetos sean el mismo o apunten al mismo, por lo que tu condición:

```
if(arr.indexOf(newPerson) === -1 )
```

Técnicamente debería cumplirse siempre ya que al comparar 2 objetos totalmente distintos nunca va a encontrarlo en el array.

El problema es que si los objetos son exactamente iguales en cuerpo pero no tienen la misma instancia entonces igual te los añadira, debido a que te los reconocera como un objeto distinto. por ende tu filtro no estaria sirviendo.

`#3`: tu ciclo es ineficiente y es innecesario, esto debido a que `indexOf` de por si solo ya haria el trabajo del ciclo por ti, por lo que el ciclo es innecesario (esto solo si quieres añadir la nueva persona una sola vez), pues podrias hacer lo siguiente:

```
if(people.indexOf(newPerson) === -1 ){
     people.push([newPerson, index]);
}
```

En vez de hacer:

```
people.forEach((curr, index, arr)=>{
  if(arr.indexOf(newPerson) === -1 ){
    people.push([newPerson, index]);
  }
})
```

Ademas, si tienes esta condicion significa que no quieres que la persona se repita:

```
if(people.indexOf(newPerson) === -1 ){
     people.push([newPerson, index]);
}
```

Por lo que si me dices que igual necesitas el ciclo, en este caso preguntaria... para qué?, si se supone la idea es no añadir la misma persona mas de una vez.

De todas maneras dejarlo de esta manera:

```
if(people.indexOf(newPerson) === -1 ){
     people.push([newPerson, index]);
}
```

También estaría errado, pues la condición sea como sea siempre se cumpliría de acuerdo a tu código debido a lo que explique mas arriba sobre instancias y eso.

Lo otro es... en tu codigo donde defines `newCharacter`?

ya que estas retornandolo pero no veo donde lo defines:

```
return newCharacter;
```

Eso solo generaría un error si no lo tienes definido en tu codigo.

**Entonces como soluciono el error?**

Comparar dos objetos de manera adecuada puede ser una tarea un tanto ineficiente, pues por esto de las instancias hacer algo tan simple como:

```
if(Objeto1 == Objeto2){

}
```

O

```
if(Objeto1 === Objeto2){

}
```

O

```
if(Objeto1.instanceOf(Objeto2)){

}
```

Todas ellas no te darían el resultado que buscas, algunas personas han inventado métodos como el de convertir ambos objetos en strings primero:

```
if(Objeto1.toString() === Objeto2.toString()){

}
```

Y aunque esto si funcione no es lo mas eficiente de realizar segun entiendo.

Por lo que otra opcion seria que crearas tu propio metodo que te enumere las propiedades y los valores y compare cada una de estas con las del otro objeto.

> Lo cual sigue siendo ineficiente, incluso mas que convertirlos
> simplemente a strings.

Por lo que yo optaria por simplemente convertir ambos a `strings` y hacer comparaciones, de esta manera el resultado seria el correcto.

Comment: Ah lo otro es que como ha dicho @Paulo Urbano Rivera mas arriba el array se encuentra vacio de primeras, y como estas recorriendo un array vacio nunca nada se te añadira ya que no hay nada que recorrer, trata de modificar el codigo con lo que te he dicho a ver que ocurre.

Comment: Wowww, excelente, gracias por tu tiempo!!

Answer (score -2):

No entiendo realmente lo que quieres hacer podrias ser mas especifico? que deberia contener el array de familia? el array de personas supongo contiene objetos personas? que relacion hay entre familia y personas?

Comment: Por favor evita hacer respuestas de este tipo, cuando tengas mayor reputación podrás comentar en cualquier lugar

Comment: El array de PEOPLE contiene a cada una de las personas, o sea  = [{nombre, edad family}, {nombre2, edad, family},...] todas las personas que creamos y agregamos con el metodo que comenté que se llama 'addPerson'... el array de families no lo estoy usando acá, es para con otro metodo agregar appelidos de familias, ejemplo ['Perez', 'Garcia', 'Sanchez'] --> luego cuando listo a la persona listPerson(family) --> le paso un apellido a este metodo, me FILTRA por apellido y devuelve todas las personas creadas bajo ese apellido (por eso acá mi pregunta es cómo le agrego un index, familyId) GRACIAS <3